# MySQL, Counting the number of occurances in a subset result

Tags: mysql

I need to select the last three records where a value is met, then count how many occurrences there are of another column in that subset.

For example:

Selecting the last three fruits where fruit name is orange along with the store name, then from those results selecting how many were store A.

So if the first result returned this:

```
Orange -- Store A
Orange -- Store B
Orange -- Store A
```

I would need a final result of 2.

Here is an amended example that I tried for my scenario

```
SELECT COUNT(SELECT COUNT(homeTeam) WHERE homeTeam = 'Arsenal') FROM `Project.Game` WHERE homeTeam = 'Arsenal' OR AwayTeam = 'Arsenal' ORDER BY homeTeam DESC limit 3
```

I have also tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Project.Games` WHERE homeTeam = 'Arsenal' IN (SELECT * FROM `Project.Games` WHERE homeTeam = 'Arsenal' OR AwayTeam = 'Arsenal' ORDER BY homeTeam DESC LIMIT 3)
```

But then I get this error: #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Thank you.

Comment: Dont tell us what you need, show us what you have tried and what you found doesnt work. SO is not here to write your code for you - put some effort in and we can assist with any mistakes or problems you run into. Read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Sorry if I'm not asking correctly, I'm just completely unsure what to do here. I may mislead the result I need in the question. The scenario I have is a list of premier league games. I need to select the last three records where team x have played, i.e Arsenal. Then count how many of those games where team x were at home. I have a column named home team and away team, among others. I tried Selecting count with a select function inside, i.e. SELECT COUNT(SELECT .. ). But that didn't work either.

Comment: Provide appropriate sample data in your question.

Comment: an amended example of what you tried?? Show what you actually tried >.<

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar sports related db so this is tested (making up column names since you gave us so litle info): `SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Home Games' FROM your_table WHERE match_number IN
(SELECT match_number FROM your_table homeclub='Arsenal' OR awayclub='Arsenal' ORDER BY match_date DESC LIMIT 3);`

Comment: thanks, I altered the above code to match my db with this statement: SELECT COUNT(*) as 'homeGames' FROM `Project.Games` WHERE homeTeam IN
(SELECT homeTeam FROM `Project.Team` WHERE homeTeam ='Arsenal' OR awayTeam ='Arsenal' ORDER BY homeTeam DESC LIMIT 3) But I get the same error from the question above.

Comment: This error: But then I get this error: #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'.

Comment: If you move the LIMIT 3 to the main query does it work?

Comment: It runs and returns a number, but the number is wrong. I'm not sure what it has calculated.

Answer (score 0):

I use SUM(CASE... like this for streaks - might be able to modify for your need: `SELECT SUM(CASE(WHEN homeTeam='Arsenal' and match_date>(SELECT match_date FROM your_table WHERE homeTeam='Arsenal' or awayTeam='Arsenal' ORDER BY match_date DESC LIMIT 3)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Home Games' FROM your_table;`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work for me. I'm just gonna run this query: SELECT homeTeam, awayTeam FROM `Project.Games` WHERE homeTeam ='Arsenal' OR awayTeam ='Arsenal' ORDER BY gameID DESC LIMIT 3. Then in the Java program i'm using, I'll count how many are home games from the result set. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to process at the scripting language level (I use PHP).  But I still think the SUM(CASE should work - maybe sorting by the gameID. Good luck.